# IIS7 classic asp request taking nearly 1 minute to repond

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

I took a copy of a website that works fine on a server (done have server access) but when I set up a website in IIS7 and run the classic asp code loading a page is taking nearly a minute. It always loads the pages but just takes forever.

Any help or suggestions would be great...

Comment: Could it be looking for other external resources? Sql? scripts? Is the app pool for the site in Integrated Mode? What are the site settings?

Comment: It looks like it is the database, will you not put an answer in so I can mark this the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you moved the code to another server elsewhere on the internet, and it is still pointing to the same database, then it could take a lot longer to do the query when compared to if the DB was on the same network as the web server. If this is the problem you'll definitely want to get a dump of the database and move it closer to the server.